# Trouble using MTOM with WCF

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

In my .NET application I have to consume a WS written in java that uses MTOM to transmit attachements.

I have tried ALL examples and suggestions found on internet with no success.

The response message (captured with Fiddler) from the WS is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 18:24:29 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870165"; start-info="text/xml"; type="text/xml"; start="<0.urn:uuid:BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870166@apache.org>"
Content-Language: it-IT
X-Client-IP: 192.168.15.175
X-Global-Transaction-ID: 136856193
Content-Length: 1699001



--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870165
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870166@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://MyServer/WS/ReadAttachement</wsa:Action><wsa:RelatesTo>da543ac1-f44a-4e9b-a319-0712790a8c78</wsa:RelatesTo></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns2:ReadAttachement xmlns:ns2="http://MyServer/WS/"><binary><idDoc>204511</idDoc><idRequest>NNNNN</idRequest><AccessCode>XXXXX</AccessCode><file><xop:Include href="cid:urn:uuid:BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870167@apache.org" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></file></binary><message><code>1</code><description>Request OK</description></message></ns2:ReadAttachement></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870165
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <urn:uuid:BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870167@apache.org>

... binary content

--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_BA16316AD1D3F515FC1454523870165--
```

and WCF says "Error creating MTOM reader", "MTOM messages must be of type 'application/xop+xml'".

In my Web.config I have the following configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000" >
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://192.168.40.149:80/WSJava/WS"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSBinding"
      contract="WSGesAl.WS" name="WSContract" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you already solved this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes, could you share with me how to do it? Thank you.